# How to combine the elements of an arbitrary number of dependent Fluxes?

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

In the non reactive world the following code snippet is nothing special:

```
interface Enhancer {
    Result enhance(Result result);
}

Result result = Result.empty();
result = fooEnhancer.enhance(result);
result = barEnhancer.enhance(result);
result = bazEnhancer.enhance(result);
```

There are three different Enhancer implementations taking a Result instance, enhancing it and returning the enhanced result. Let's assume the order of the enhancer calls matters.

Now what if these methods are replaced by reactive variants returning a `Flux<Result>`? Because the methods depend on the result(s) of the preceding method, we cannot use `combineLatest` here.

A possible solution could be:

```
Flux.just(Result.empty())
    .switchMap(result -> first(result)
        .switchMap(result -> second(result)
            .switchMap(result -> third(result))))
    .subscribe(result -> doSomethingWith(result));
```

Note that the `switchMap` calls are nested. As we are only interested in the final result, we let `switchMap` switch to the next flux as soon as new events are emitted in preceding fluxes.

Now let's try to do it with a dynamic number of fluxes. Non reactive (without fluxes), this would again be nothing special:

```
List<Enhancer> enhancers = <ordered list of different Enhancer impls>;
Result result = Result.empty();
for (Enhancer enhancer : enhancers) {
    result = enhancer.enhance(result);
}
```

But how can I generalize the above reactive example with three fluxes to deal with an arbitrary number of fluxes?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using recursion:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface FluxProvider {
    Flux<Result> get(Result result);
}

// recursive method creating the final Flux
private Flux<Result> cascadingSwitchMap(Result input, List<FluxProvider> fluxProviders, int idx) {
    if (idx < fluxProviders.size()) {
        return fluxProviders.get(idx).get(input).switchMap(result -> cascadingSwitchMap(result, fluxProviders, idx + 1));
    }
    return Flux.just(input);
}

// code using the recursive method
List<FluxProvider> fluxProviders = new ArrayList<>();
fluxProviders.add(fooEnhancer::enhance);
fluxProviders.add(barEnhancer::enhance);
fluxProviders.add(bazEnhancer::enhance);

cascadingSwitchMap(Result.empty(), fluxProviders, 0)
        .subscribe(result -> doSomethingWith(result));
```

But maybe there is a more elegant solution using an operator/feature of project-reactor. Does anybody know such a feature? In fact, the requirement doesn't seem to be such an unusual one, is it?

Answer (score 0):

`switchMap` feels inappropriate here. If you have a `List<Enhancer>` by the time the `Flux` pipeline is *declared*, why not apply a logic close to what you had in imperative style:

```
List<Enhancer> enhancers = <ordered list of different Enhancer impls>;
Mono<Result> resultMono = Mono.just(Result.empty)
for (Enhancer enhancer : enhancers) {
    resultMono = resultMono.map(enhancer::enhance); //previousValue -> enhancer.enhance(previousValue)
}
return resultMono;
```

That can even be performed later at subscription time for even more dynamic resolution of the enhancers by wrapping the whole code above in a `Mono.defer(() -> {...})` block.

Comment: With `Mono` and `map` that may be ok. But the enhancers return a `Flux`. Inside the loop I therefore cannot write `resultFlux = resultFlux.map(enhancer::enhance);` but have to use `flatMap` or `switchMap` instead. I forgot to mention that the fluxes should be subscribed on in different threads to be able to emit their events in parallel. When a flux emits an event, the following flux should stop computing its results based on the first input but start again using the new input. This behavior can only be achieved by fluxes combined with nested `switchMap`, I think.